# Android using Intellij Version 14 - Update XML References only in current XML resource file

Tags: java, android, xml, intellij-idea

I am using  Intellij Idea Version 14 for Android development. I have recently upgraded to version 14. While editing resource XML, when I change ID of any component (e.g TextView or Button) it asks a question "Update usages as well?" "This will update all XML references and Java R field references." Clicking yes changes all files where same ID is used. Version 13 was doing only in that file. Now the name is changed in entire project wherever it is used. I do not want to change code in other files. Here is a example.

File 1: First.Java and First.XML has textview with ID textViewPersonName

File 2: Second.java and Second.XML has textView with ID textViewPersonName

Now I want to change Second.XML, textViewPersonName to textViewPersonFullName. On changing this file Intellij 14 changes all files (i.e.First.Java and First.XML ) and updates  textViewPersonName in the first files to  textViewPersonFullName.

How do I change only in currently used file (i.e. Second.XML) only. Is there any setting?

Comment: AFAIK if you @+id/textViewPersonFullName that name is in the (global) resource name namespace, so it appears that the rename is doing the "right" thing, treating it as the same name everywhere (even though you want it to restrict itself to that xml/java file pair.) FWIW. You might try setting `tools:context` to point to the activity (attribute described by http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes), the renaming code may pay attention to that.

Comment: I have added the tools:context in the XML resource file. Intellij still goes and try changing the other files. Here is part of my XML file <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="1dp" tools:context=".ContactLogActivity">

Comment: Yeah, I think you're probably SOL. I'm no expert though. You can install IntelliJ13 side-by-side with 14 (or at least that's fine on MacOS), and that's what I would do if I were you. Use 13 to fix all the terrible Eclipse identifiers, then proceed with your regularly scheduled programming in 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you refactor a id with the shortcut [SHIFT]+[F6] you can click on preview and a second window opens:

[image]

Here you can right click on the selected line and exclude that refactoring:

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't see this dialog. Please give more elaborated steps.